# Логическая ошибка в функции для получения информации из БД

Tags: python-3.x, функции, sqlite3

Я написал функцию для извлечения данных из таблицы, но она не работает.

```py
def read_db():
    connect = sqlite3.connect('filename.db', check_same_thread=False)
    cursor.execute('''SELECT user_id FROM users''')
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    return data
```

Функцию использую так:

```py
def handle_text(message):
    if message.text == 'some text':
        user_id = str(message.from_user.id)
        data = read_db()
        if user_id in data:
            keyboard.custom1(message)
        else:
            keyboard.custom2(message)
```

Oшибка заключается в том, что функцию должна собирать значения одного столбца.
Затем, я сравниваю эти значения со строкой на наличие одинковой строки. Но при том, что в БД есть строка с которой я сравниваю, выполняется блок `else`.

Как это исправить?

Comment: Что именно не работает? Какая ошибка?

Comment: я пытаюсь реализовать сравнение со строкой. Для этого я импортирую функцию и реализовываю конструкцию if else, но строка не находитя, хотя в бд она есть

Comment: Резюмирую: этому вопросу не хватает: 1. Описания конкретной возникающей ошибки; 2. Полного (или хотя бы воспроизводимого) кода; 3. Объяснений по поводу странного `connect` во второй строке.

Comment: 1 ошибка заключается в том, что функцию должна собирать значения одного столбца. Затем я сравниваю эти значения со строкой на наличие одинковой строки. Но при том что в бд есть строка с которой я сравниваю, выполняется блок else. 2. Мне нужно исправить функцию сбора данных из бд 3 
`connect = sqlite3.connect(file'name.db', check_same_thread=False)`

Comment: @kriper5000 Извините, после слов "1 ошибка заключается в том" ожидалось описание ошибки, а не того, что должна делать функция. (Ошибка – то, что идёт не так, проблема в Вашей программе. Желательно в виде сообщения об ошибке выданного программой)

Comment: Изначально в вопросе не было слова об ошибке. Я достаточно ясно объснил что не так с функцией.

Comment: Хорошо, я оставлю этот вопрос тем, для кого Ваши разъяснения действительно являются "достаточно ясными".

Comment: Я перенёс описание ошибки из вашего комментария. Это же логическая ошибка, верно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import sqlite3 as mdb

connection = mdb.connect('database.db')
cursor     = connection.cursor()

cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM students')

print(*cursor.fetchall(), sep="\n")
```

---

```
(1400609, 'Sachin', 'Civil', 3, 8054448071, 'Rayya')
(1400610, 'Вася', 'Information Technology', 7, '12345 12345', '1223123122312231223')
(1400612, 'Вася', 'Civil', 2, '12233 44', 'фывфыывфыыв')
(1400613, 'Nick', 'Information Technology', 8, '123 45 67', 'axaxxZXZXxZXX')
(1400614, 'adsadA', 'Electrical', 3, 123, 'eqwdqwd')
(1400677, 'ййй', 'aaa', 3, 1313, 'asasd12212')
```

---

**Update**

```
import sqlite3 as mdb

def read_db():
    connection = mdb.connect('database.db')
    cursor     = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM students')

    data = []
    for row in cursor.fetchall():
        data.append(row[0])
    return data

print(read_db())
```

---

```
[1400609, 1400610, 1400612, 1400613, 1400614, 1400677]
```

Answer (score 3):

Используйте реляционные базы данных как реляционные базы данных, а не как медленный аналог текстовых файлов. ;)

Реляционные БД сами умеют искать данные:

```
def user_exists(cursor, user_id):
    sql = """SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE user_id = ?"""
    parms = (user_id,)
    cursor.execute(sql, parms)
    cnt = cursor.fetchone()[0]
    return bool(cnt)
```

использование:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('filename.db', check_same_thread=False)
cursor = conn.cursor()

# ...

if user_exists(cursor, user_id):
    ...
```